# Detect string/user input language

Tags: android

I wanted to know if there is a way to detect if the user's input is in greek charset.

**Edit:**
Just to be more clear, I need to recognize the language the user types and not the phone's locale. 
For example, my phone is in English and let's say my keyboard is in Russian, the getDefault() returns "en", but I need to have "ru" at that point.

I do not know if this is available out of the box from android, maybe an approach to detect the string's character codes and see if is in English alphabet or in another. Any points on this?
I imagine something like 
`if character belongs to K then is English` 
`(where K is the essemble of english characters)`

**Solution:**

Finally I used regular expression to determine if the string is in English.

```
String pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9. ]+$";
if (string.matches(pattern) 
   // is English
else
   // is not English
```

If someone has to propose a better solution I will mark it as answer.

Comment: The running IME should conform to the user's locale.  If it doesn't, I don't know if there's anything - as an app developer - you can do to detect/correct it.

Comment: This is what I was looking so far, thanks @Vame it helped

Answer (score 12):

You can use following method instead of pattern matching:

```
boolean isEnglish = true;
for ( char c : s.toCharArray() ) {
  if ( Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) != Character.UnicodeBlock.BASIC_LATIN ) {
    isEnglish = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much darkmist.... This is what i need... I just has to know isEnglish or not..

Answer (score 2):

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("gr")
```

In other way:

```
 contains(Charset)
```

**EDIT:**

After some more time of browsing, I have come across [CharsetDetector](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/CharsetDetector.html) and [Character Set Detection](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection).

Here you have method `detect()` but am not sure how best this can be utilized.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess this one returns the phone's locale. I need the current locale of the keyboard / input string language.

Answer (score 0):

As Siva suggests, you can check the user's locale.

In Android, this can be done by using [Locale.getDefault()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDefault%28%29).  Although I wouldn't strictly compare it to a 2-letter code, current Android implementation has it being a 2-letter language code, an underscore, and a two-letter country code.  Ie., `de_US` would be `German as spoken in the United States`.

This is not the way the industry is moving, but its the best-supported pattern as of Java 6.  Java 7, once supported by Android should support [ISO 639 alpha-3](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) codes that are more future-proof.